# Create a file from a file in Yii Framework

Tags: php, file, yii, frameworks

Hellou I'm having problems with this code.. I want to make a file through this URL as I can without framework, the file is an HTML and I want to extract its content to show it in a mmesage with file_get_contents. I mean, I attach the html to the body of the message to send it by e-mail (using PHPMailer).
This is the way how I do it with PHP only:

```
$body = file_get_contents('firma.html');
```

This is the way how I do it with Yii Framework:

```
$file = file(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/vendor/firma.html');
```

then use file_get_contents.
I have tried: Import, basepath, baseurl and no one could help me.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the CFile extension : http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/cfile/

And then you could open a file like :

```
$file = CFile::getInstance(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/vendor/firma.html');
$contents = $file->getContents();
```

Or to write a file:

```
$file = CFile::getInstance(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/vendor/firma.html');
$file->setContents('bla');
```